# In Terraform how to create an Azure Virtual Machine from a custom VHD

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

In Terraform how to create an Azure Virtual Machine from a custom VHD which is in a storage account.
This is part of the main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "osdisk" {

 name                 = "${var.hostname}-osdisk"
 location             = "${var.location}"
resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf_azure_guide.name}"
storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
create_option        = "Import"
storage_account_id = "xxx"
source_uri           = "${var.source_vhd_path}"
disk_size_gb         = "31"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "site" {
name                = "${var.hostname}-site"
location            = "${var.location}"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf_azure_guide.name}"
vm_size             = "${var.vm_size}"
network_interface_ids         = ["${azurerm_network_interface.tf-guide-nic.id}"]
delete_os_disk_on_termination = "true"

storage_os_disk {
name              = "${var.hostname}-osdisk"
caching           = "ReadWrite" 
os_type           = "linux"
create_option     = "Attach"  
managed_disk_id   = "${azurerm_managed_disk.osdisk.id}"
managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"

 }

 /*os_profile {
computer_name  = "${var.hostname}"
admin_username = "${var.admin_username}"
admin_password = "${var.admin_password}"

}*/

os_profile_linux_config {   
disable_password_authentication = true
}
```

Is this the right way to create a vm from a custom vhd(generated from an iso) in azure? The VHD has its own OS. But terraform asks me to specify Linux or Windows, so i specified Linux which i think maybe the closest.

Also I want an admin_username and password so that i can connect to the vm, but if i speify os_type in storage_os_disk, I cant use os_profile. How can I get around this. I am new to Terraform and it is very confusing.Any help will be greatly aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way you used is right. There is one way as I know to create the VM from a custom VHD file that stored in the Storage Account. I don't think when you set the `os_type` and then cannot use the `os_profile`. The issue in your Terraform code is that you set the `os_profile_linux_config` as:

```
os_profile_linux_config {   
  disable_password_authentication = true
}
```

It means you disable password authentication and it causes that you cannot set the admin_password. So if you want to set the admin user and password to connect the VM, then you need to set them like this:

```
os_profile {
  computer_name  = "${var.hostname}"
  admin_username = "${var.admin_username}"
  admin_password = "${var.admin_password}"

}

os_profile_linux_config {   
  disable_password_authentication = false
}
```

If you have any more questions, please give me the messages to let me know. I'm glad to give you a favor.